# How to know name of class in decorator for function-method?

Tags: python

I have a simple timemark-decorator for function:

```
def dec_timemark(f):
    def tmp(*args, **kwargs):
        sys.stdout.write(strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S") + ' ' + f.__name__ +
                                                         ' begin' + "\n" )
        res = f(*args, **kwargs)
        sys.stdout.write(strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S") + ' ' + f.__name__ +
                                                         ' end' + "\n"     )
        return res
    return tmp
```

typical usage:

```
class Task():
    @dec_timemark
    def make_torrent():
        sleep(10)
```

But how to add to this `decorator` name of the `class`? (Not to log: "`make_torrent begin`", but "`Task.make_torrent begin`" for example ) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the decorated routine is invoked as a method, you can pull the classname out of the `self` parameter:

```
def dump(f):
    def decorated(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'Class: {0}'.format(self.__class__.__name__)
        print 'Args passed to decorated function: {0}'.format(args)
        print 'Keyword args passed to decorated function: {0}'.format(kwargs)
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorated

class Test(object):
    """
    >>> Test().test('arg1', 'arg2', kwarg1='kwval1')
    Class: Test
    Args passed to decorated function: ('arg1', 'arg2')
    Keyword args passed to decorated function: {'kwarg1': 'kwval1'}
    """
    @dump
    def test(*args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to access that information within the scope of `dec_timemark()` itself, since the class doesn't exist yet. However, when `tmp()` is called, the first argument will be `self`, since `.make_torrent()` is being called as an instance method. Thus, `type(self).__name__` should give you the class name.

Modifying your example:

```
def dec_timemark(f):
    def tmp(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cname = type(self).__name__
        sys.stdout.write(strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S") + ' ' + cname + '.' + f.__name__ +
                                                     ' begin' + "\n" )
        res = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        sys.stdout.write(strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S") + ' ' + cname + '.' + f.__name__ +
                                                     ' end' + "\n"     )
        return res
    return tmp
```

Comment: `self.__name__` doesn't work. You have to access the attribute on the class, not the instance.